# How do I make a PowerShell profile if my profile path contains an apostrophe?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to set up a PowerShell profile so all of my machines have a common profile. I'm making each machine's profile run a script in my dropbox so I can update all of them easier.

I thought the problem was I didn't know dot-source syntax well, but it turns out PowerShell really doesn't like that the path to my documents folder has an apostrophe. The full path is:

```
d:\Owen's Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

If I delete that file, PowerShell starts up fine (of course, without the modifications I want.) If I create that file, I get an error when PowerShell starts up:

```
The string starting:
At line:1 char:75
+ . 'D:\Owen`'s Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 <<<< '
is missing the terminator: '.
At line:1 char:76
+ . 'D:\Owen`'s Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1' <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

It can't be my fault, because the script itself is empty. Deleting the empty file makes it go away, creating the new file makes the error come back. Surely Microsoft anticipated profile paths with apostrophes?

*Update*
Crud. [Looks like an old issue.](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/278008/powershell-errors-with-apostrophe-in-path#tabs) Maybe there's not a workaround. :(

*Update 2*
I had a conversation with [@Lee_Holmes](http://twitter.com/#!/lee_holmes) on Twitter about this. Apparently it's been fixed in some super-awesome internal Microsoft version, but there's no hotfix available and no time table for fixes since PSH is now a Windows Component. That makes Roman Kuzmin's answer below the most appropriate answer (use one of the global profiles), or perhaps "rename your My Documents folder" which hasn't been mentioned yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The similar bug is reported and presumably acknowledged:
[Powershell errors with apostrophe in path](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/278008/powershell-errors-with-apostrophe-in-path)

The error message is different though, due to a different PowerShell version, more likely.

Perhaps there is no direct workaround: this faulty call is not under our control. If renaming of the troublesome directory is not an option then perhaps an alternative location of the profile can be a suitable solution. Try to put your profile to `$PsHome`.

```
> man about_profiles
...
For example, the Windows PowerShell console supports the following basic
profile files. The profiles are listed in precedence order. The first
profile has the highest precedence. 

Description                Path
-----------                ----
Current User, Current Host $Home\[My ]Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Profile.ps1
Current User, All Hosts    $Home\[My ]Documents\Profile.ps1
All Users, Current Host    $PsHome\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
All Users, All Hosts       $PsHome\Profile.ps1
...
```

The last two profile locations should work for you (unless `$PsHome` contains problem characters, indeed).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following escape sequence:

```
d:\Owen`'s Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

Comment: You don't understand. No line of code that is executing is under my control. The profile file is *empty*, and the error occurs if it exists. I can't use an escape sequence because there's nowhere for me to write code.

Comment: my bad, I'm not sure how you can resolve this in that case aside from removing the apostrophe from your folder name. it seems that microsoft in fact did not anticipate profile paths with apostrophes.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue myself.  I am running **PSv5**.  I tried to get around it using the grave accent as well but I found that didn't work for me.  So I thought "let's see what intellisense does with it" and sure enough it found the solution:

**Use two apostrophes!**

```
PS> $path = 'd:\Owen''s Documents'
PS> $path
d:\Owen's Documents
```